The minimum width of the OutlinedButton does not change
I try to change the minimum width of the OutlinedButton, but its minimum width is always 48 pixels.
Code:
class _GenreListWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const _GenreListWidget();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<String> genresList = [
      'All',
      'eBooks',
      'New',
      't',
      'Bestseller',
      'Audiobooks',
      'Fantasy',
      'a'
    ];
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          for (int i = 0; i < genresList.length; i++)
            _GenreTileWidget(genresList[i]),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _GenreTileWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  const _GenreTileWidget(this.title);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return OutlinedButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      style: const ButtonStyle(
        minimumSize: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Size(0, 0)),
        padding: MaterialStatePropertyAll(
          EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 6),
        ),
        shape: MaterialStatePropertyAll(
          RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      child: Text(
        title,
        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
      ),
    );
  }
}

View
I used minimumSize: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Size(0, 0))
and IntrinsicWidth(child: OutlinedButton(...))
but it didn't help.
I want to get a list of items without gaps.
But I could write a personal button without OutlinedButton(), where this problem does not exist.
Code:
class _GenreTileWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final String title;

  const _GenreTileWidget(this.title);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        debugPrint('Select genre: $title');
      },
      child: DecoratedBox(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
            color: const Color(0xFF7E675E),
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
            horizontal: 10,
            vertical: 6,
          ),
          child: Text(
            title,
            style: const TextStyle(
              fontSize: 16,
              color: Color(0xFF7E675E),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


I was reading the source code of OutlinedButton widget and I found a property it's using to set the padding, it's called tapTargetSize.
If you set tapTargetSize to MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap, it works as expected.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return OutlinedButton(
      onPressed: () {},
      style: const ButtonStyle(
        minimumSize: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Size(0, 0)),
        tapTargetSize: MaterialTapTargetSize.shrinkWrap,
        padding: MaterialStatePropertyAll(
          EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10, vertical: 6),
        ),
        shape: MaterialStatePropertyAll(
          RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      child: Text(
        title,
        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
      ),
    );
  }

Result

More info: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialTapTargetSize.html
